# Add some text while output to file

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

Assume I have this command: `./clang-$j.out >> clang-result.txt` and the each output for `clang-$j.out` is a fixed-length hash value (each program per line), however, I want to distinguish them by adding a prefix to the beginning of each line. For example, I want to add `"1-"` where is number comes from the variable `j`.

I've made some effort to do this but I still cannot figure out how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output the number from the variable before running each program; in your loop:

```
printf "%s-" "${j}" >> clang-result.txt
./clang-$j.out >> clang-result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like

```
prefix=`basename $0 | cut -d"." -f1 | cut -d"-" -f2`
echo ${prefix}-HASH
```

in the clang-$j.out scripts. It should give you the sequence in the prefix variable. Now you can use this in the output of the script.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however I will not know the sequence of variable j before running them, some .out files will be skipped if the program won't run. Is there a method to add prefix while my script is running?

Comment: I suppose that you know it when you create the script `clang-$j.out` since it is part of the filename. Do not really know what is done in this script nor how it is created so I can only get the value of `$j` this way (out of the filename).